# D3 Collapsible Force Layout adding nodes to the layout dynamically

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, visualization

I have some issues with adding nodes dynamically in my collapsible force layout. My data set will be created dynamically so the object will change every time the force layout is created so I used an example from a D3 mbostock where they used a local object instead of loading a JSON as my initial starting point.

I have added pan + zoom but adding a node seems to not work. I have a static object (for test purposes) and my addNode function is called on click of a node. I am trying to add the nodes through:
`var childrenTest=[
     {"name": "Title", "size": 3938},
     {"name": "Title", "size": 3938},
     {"name": "Title", "size": 3938}
     ];`

`g.data.children[1].children = childrenTest;`and then running the `update();` which is supposed to flatten the data for collapsing and create links between nodes before updating them.

Unfortunately, it seems that when I do this it completely breaks my graph creating a floating cluster offset from my main graph and links and nodes go missing. I was wondering if I could get some assistance in figuring out why it will not add the nodes properly.

Here is an example of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/Diffusion_net/hu6t2ywb/9/

(Note: the addnode function will only add the node on childless node click once due to the check for test purposes only)

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While adding new nodes dynamically, the key is to map the id's (look at your flatten function which assigns id's to the nodes like this -> nodes.id = ++i;) of newly created nodes in such a way that it should be unique and should not overlap with the existing id's of the nodes(which are already present on the layout). Not doing so can lead to the unpredictable behavior as in your case.

One way to handle this is to remember how many nodes are already present on the layout so that you can assign new id values to the newly created nodes. See the modified flatten function below.

```
var alreadyNodes = 0; //no of nodes already present on the layout
   function flatten(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var nodes = [],
    i = alreadyNodes; //offset to the node id
    var flattenNodes = 0; //no of nodes flatten under the current node
       //count only children (not _children)
       //note that it doesn't count any descendents of collapsed _children
       //rather elegant?
    function recurse(node) {
           if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
           if (!node.id) {
              node.id = ++i;
              flattenNodes++;
           }
           nodes.push(node);
    }
    recurse(data);
       //Done:
    alreadyNodes = alreadyNodes + flattenNodes;
    return nodes;
}
```

Here *alreadyNodes* stores the no of nodes that are already present on the layout and *flattenNodes* counts the no of nodes to be added to the layout. *alreadyNodes* gets updated before returning the nodes (last line). Check how an offset to the id is given every time flatten is called which ensures that newly nodes gets new id's.

I hope this helps.